# Proceeding to build a template with Fireworks

Tags: java, php, html, joomla, fireworks

I have a image open-able in Fireworks and I was told to use it as a Joomla Template.
I'd like to have some tips on how to begin programming it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't do this in fireworks. Making a Joomla template requires knowledge of at least HTML, CSS and a bit of PHP. If you know how to build websites in general, you can find tutorials on how to build Joomla templates [on their wiki](http://docs.joomla.org/Joomla!_1.5_Template_Tutorial).

If you have no experience in making websites what so ever, you really shouldn't start by making a template for a CMS. You can't simply use an image as a template.

I don't know who told you to do this, but from the way you ask this question, I must admit I think you are in way over your head! :S

Comment: I understand your point. I do have experience in making websites in Joomla, but never done anything more than editing the CSS of a downloaded template, which is why I understand you, as I've never created a template.
So programming it from scratch is rather confusing, but I'm sure I'll succeed with a good guidance!

Comment: If you don't know php, you could try to find a template that features the things you'd like on your template, and then re-CSS that template to look like your image. You say you already sliced your image, so that is a good start there. Giving a detailed step-by-step guide is not really realistic on these forums, but if you have tried altering the design of templates before, that would probably be the way to go :)